# Retrieve the last div element if contains string in Success response ajax call using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to change the background color of div if the div contains particular string. I have used ajax call and appended the html through jquery. I am trying using **$response.has('string')**, but this does not change the background color of the last div in list though it contains the string. How can I target the last div if it contains string?
PS: This condition must be written in ajax call, success:function().

PFB my code which I am trying to execute on local machine:

```
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
            $.get('sitemap.xml', function(d){

            $('.contentWrapper').append('<div class="mainWrapper" />');

            $(d).find('url').each(function(index){

                    var $url = $(this); 

                    var urlLoc = $url.find('loc').text();

                    var html = '<div class="mainContainer"><div class="leftContent"> ' + urlLoc + '</div>';
                    $('#loading-image').show();     
            $.ajax({
            crossOrigin:true,
            cache:false,
            async:false,
            url:urlLoc,
            success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var $response=$(data);
            var dataToday = $response.filter('#pagemainwrapper').attr('class');
            html += '<div class="rightContent"> '+ dataToday + ' </div></div>';
              if($response.has('experiencelanding'))
                {

                    $(".mainContainer:contains('experiencelanding')").each(function(){
                    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
                    });

                }   


             },
             complete: function(){
                $('#loading-image').hide();
              }
            });
            $('div.mainWrapper').append($(html));
            });

            });

            });
```

Any help much appreciated.
Thanks a lot in advance.
Ashwini

Comment: Share the part of your code that reflects your intention :)

Comment: I can't see your code :(

Comment: Hi Ahmad, Have updated my code now.

Answer (score 0):

I guess $response is a jQuery object containg a node list. then you can Use this:

```
$response:contains('string').css('background-color', 'yourColor';
```

Comment: Thanks for your response MadClown. But unfortunately the last div item is not taking that background color.